# Usual notation for Fréchet filter and principal ultrafilters

Tags: notation, set-theory, filters

Given a set $S$ we can define the [filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28mathematics%29#Filter_on_a_set) consisting of all complements of finite sets, which is usually called [Fréchet filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frechet_filter) or cofinite filter.

For any $a\in S$ the set $\{A\subseteq S; a\in A\}$ is the *principal ultrafilter* defined by $a$.

What are "standard" (common, frequently used) notations for these two filters? What notation would you recommend?

I will be using this notation mostly in connection with $\mathcal F$-limits (see e.g. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultralimit#Limit_of_a_sequence_of_points_with_respect_to_an_ultrafilter) or [Hindman-Strauss, p.63](http://books.google.com/books?id=KYXgdiegKDsC&pg=PA63#v=onepage&q&f=false)) and [Stone-Čech compactification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification).

---

For the Fréchet filter I was able to find

- $\mathrm{Fr}$, $\mathrm{Fr}(S)$ or $\mathfrak{Fr}$ , e.g. [this thesis](http://www.diss.fu-berlin.de/diss/servlets/MCRFileNodeServlet/FUDISS_derivate_000000006649/Krautzberger_Idempotent_Filters_and_Ultrafilters.pdf?hosts=) or [this paper](http://www.franko.lviv.ua/faculty/mechmat/Departments/Topology/banpap/cohsem.pdf).
- $\operatorname{Cof}(S)$, e.g. [this paper](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~apalmigi/notes_on_ultrafilters.pdf)
- This question asks about the notation for the dual ideal: [Notation for the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55591/notation-for-the-set-of-all-finite-subsets-of-mathbbn)

---

For principal ultrafilters I found:

- $\mathcal F_a$, e.g. [here](http://www.math.toronto.edu/drorbn/classes/9293/131/ultra.pdf)
- $\pi_a$, e.g. [this paper](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~apalmigi/notes_on_ultrafilters.pdf)
- $e(a)$, e.g. [Hindman-Strauss](http://books.google.com/books?id=KYXgdiegKDsC&pg=PA50) (I think the authors chose the notation $e$ to indicate that this gives the *embedding* of discrete space on $A$ into the Stone-Čech compactification.)
- IIRC I have seen $a^*$ (in the context of Stone-Čech compactification), but I cannot find an example right now.

Since points of $A$ and principal ultrafilters are usually identified (i.e. $A$ is identified with the corresponding subspace of $\beta A$) maybe it would make sense in some situations to denote the principal ultrafilter given by $a$ again as $a$, but I think this would be too confusing.

Comment: In the context of $\beta\omega$ it’s not uncommon to denote by $n$ the principal ultrafilter over $n$, though I’m pretty sure that I recently saw $n^*$ in a proof that every fixed ultrafilter is in the centre of $\langle\beta\omega,+\rangle$. In general it seems common to use $\mathscr{U}_a$ when $\mathscr{U}$ is used for a generic ultrafilter, $p_a$ when $p$ is used for a generic ultrafilter, etc.

Comment: Since I tend to use uppercase script letters for filters and ultrafilters, I’ve always used $\mathscr{F}$ for the Fréchet filter. (I corrected your *cofinal* to *cofinite*.)

Comment: I think all the notations are fine, except $e(a)$ (why on earth $e(\cdot)$?) and I don't like the notation $a^\ast$ either: this is because it seems to indicate a contravariant dependence which it isn't.

Comment: @t.b.: I expect that $e(a)$ stems from the common use of $e$ to denote an embedding. *My* objection to $a^*$ is that I’m accustomed to $A^*$ denoting the set of free ultrafilters containing $A$, i.e., $\operatorname{cl}_{\beta D}(A)\setminus A$.

Comment: Thanks @Brian, that's an even better reason. Martin edited the explanation "e for embedding" in and this seems to be the right interpretation. The letter $e$ could also stand for "evaluation" if you think of the Stone-Čech compactification in terms of the Gel'fand spectrum of $C_b(X)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I've tried to put it into CW bellow, I hope it's ok. Feel free to edit the CW or write another answer, if you think there's something that should be added. So far I have used $\mathcal F_0$ for Frechet filter - which I did not like too much, since it might be confused with principal ultrafilter. I'll probably try $\mathcal F_{F}$ or something similar. As I am using $\mathcal F$, $\mathcal G$ to denote arbitrary filter, I cannot use Brian's suggestion. BTW I use $\mathcal F$ and not $\mathscr F$ - I am not sure whether it is unusual.

Comment: P.S. I did not even ping you - I see that you're both on this site a lot, so you'll probably notice that the question was bumped, in the case you want to look at it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the above comments by [Brian M. Scott](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12042/brian-m-scott) and [t.b.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/5363/t-b): It seems that there is no generally accepted notation.

Notation for principal ultrafilters:

- In general it seems common to use $\mathscr{U}_a$ when $\mathscr{U}$ is used for a generic ultrafilter, $p_a$ when $p$ is used for a generic ultrafilter, etc.
- From the notations mentioned in the post, at least in some situations, $e(a)$ and $a^*$ are not advisable. (The letter $e$ is chosen rather arbitrarily. The notation $a^*$ might be confused $A^*$, which is often used for $\operatorname{cl}_{\beta D}(A)\setminus A$.)

Answer (score 1):

A principal filter corresponding to a set $A$ is sometimes denoted as $\uparrow A$ (or $\uparrow^U A$ to mean a filter on the set $U$).