# Notation for infinite coinfinite subsets.

Tags: notation, set-theory

Call a subset $A\subset X$ of an infinite set $X$ **coinfinite** if $X\setminus A$ is infinite.

Is there a standard way to denote the infinite coinfinite subsets of an infinite set (in particular of $\omega$)?

I have made up $\mathrm{Spl}(\omega)$, motivated by it being the set of those subsets of $\omega$ that split $\omega$, but I was wondering if there is a more common notation.

Comment: My understanding is that a subset $S$ of a set is *cofinite* if $S^c$ is finite, and similarly, $S$ is *coinfinite* if $S^c$ is infinite. I guess this is not the definition you have in mind. Could you please give your definition of these notions?

Comment: Do you mean "infinite coinfinite"? These are the sets that split $\omega$.

Comment: @Jonathan Oops, indeed, I mean infinite coinfinite

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I meant to write infinite coinfinite, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I don't think there is a standard notation for this, annoyingly. I've seen things like "$\mathcal{P}_{biinf}(X)$" or "$[X]^{biinf}$" or similar, but not something established.

Answer (score 2):

A [standard notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55591/notation-for-the-set-of-all-finite-subsets-of-mathbbn) for the class of infinite subsets of $X$ is $[X]^{\geq \aleph_0}$.

On the other hand, the Fréchet filter (class of cofinite subsets) of $X$ [can be denoted by](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88216/usual-notation-for-fr%C3%A9chet-filter-and-principal-ultrafilters) $\text{Fr}(X)$.

Therefore, your set can be denoted by $[X]^{\geq \aleph_0} - \text{Fr}(X)$.