# Notation showing a set is non-empty and finite

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Does there exist any mathematical notation that would indicate that a set $V$ is non-empty and finite? Or would I have to write this out in words?

Comment: You can write $S\ne \emptyset,|S|<\infty$

Comment: For some additional suggestions for finite, see [this link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55591/notation-for-the-set-of-all-finite-subsets-of-mathbbn) (one can easily add in the non-empty part). Best not to do it, usually. Words are good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To say that $V$ is not empty you can either say so or write $V\neq\emptyset$
or $|V|>0$.

To say that $V$ is finite you can either say so or write $|V|<\aleph_{0}$.

So you can write something like $0<|V|<\aleph_{0}$ to say that
$V$ is a non-empty finite set.

**Added:** in many context (mainly non set theory wise where just writing infinity is not common) you can replace $\aleph_{0}$ with $\infty$

Comment: @ZhenLin - corrected, thanks for pointing the typo out

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) notation. The cardinality of a set $A$ is usually denoted as $|A|$. If the set is non-empty and finite, you can express this as:

$$
A \neq \emptyset, |A| < \infty
$$

However, I think that explaining this in words would be clearer.

Comment: So in that case could I also do $0 < |A| < inf$?

Comment: @A.R.S. That's another way to put it. It would work too.

Comment: @A.R.S. : I wouldn't use *inf*, $\infty$ is really more appropriate. The reason for this is that the word *inf* is mostly used for infimums in analysis, so your last sentence is just as readable as $a+\% b=! ?$ for some people. It would be understood but not at first sight.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Yea you're right - I just didn't know how to obtain the infinity symbol on the comment :P But thank you for the tip!

Comment: @A.R.S. Use this: `$\infty$`.

Comment: @A.R.S. : Sorry, I didn't guess that this was the issue. I guess Ayman's comment does the trick.