# What is the correct mathematical notation for a finite set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My random variable $y$ belongs to a finite set of real numbers. I am writing a document and I need to write something like $y\in \mathbb{R}$. what should I put next to $\mathbb{R}$ which shows that its a finite set?

Comment: What do you mean by that the random variable "belongs to a finite set of real numbers"? Do you mean that there are only finitely many values that the random variable takes on with nonzero probability?

Comment: There is no "correct notation". But this was discussed several times before. [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121553/is-there-a-notation-for-being-a-finite-subset-of) is probably a good start.

Comment: You could say something like $y\in \{y_1,...,y_n\}\subseteq\mathbb R$.

Comment: @ qaphla . … thats exactly what I mean. e.g $y\in[1.5,0.5,0.-0.5]$. This set has finite number of entries and each entry belongs to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Use curly braces (with latex, by using `\{` and `\}`) around your finite set of numbers, and that's exactly what you can write.

Comment: Thanks guys….atleast now I know that I am not missing something here. This leaves a room for us to be creative :)