Notation for the set $\{[x, \infty) : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$?
Is there a special notation for the set $\{[x, \infty) : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$? This is, the set of all connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that have a minimum element and no supremum.
(Incidentally, this is the set of all filters of the lattice $(\mathbb{R}, \max, \min))$.

Why is this being downvoted? The question is similar to, for example, this well-received question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55591/notation-for-the-set-of-all-finite-subsets-of-mathbbn

That question is from 12 years ago. Standards have changed a lot since then.

What is a continuous subset? Do you mean a connected subset?

Continuity is about functions, not sets. What do you mean by continuous subsets?

Also, $(x,+\infty)$ is a filter on that lattice, too.

It was connected, my mistake. Fixed it.

To my knowledge there isn’t.

It's the image of $\mathbb{R}$ under the $(0, 1)$-Yoneda embedding, so you could be tongue-in-cheek and write $よ(\mathbb{R})$.
